# PHP - MySQL - Backup database daily

Tags: php, mysql, backup, database-backups

I have developed an agenda which works (server-side) with PHP and MySQL. The last thing I need to do is to make an authomatic daily backup of the database.

This is what I have thought may be the easiest: Write a php script which once every 24hs saves a file(Whose name would be a timestamp) in certain folder in the server. Combining this with time machine or some other backup software to backup this folder into an external disk should be enough.

So now, the questions are: How do I make a php script to run automatically once per day? How do I save a file with sql backup from a php script?(Similar to phpMyAdmin export as sql)

Thanks!

Comment: Also you probably want to save the backup off your main server. No point in making a backup if the backup gets destroyed too.

Comment: Don't use PHP to do this

Comment: hello guys i know this post a bit old but i do have a follow up question after reading your answers what if i wanted the backup to be sent off via email or specifically to be uploaded into a google drive how do i achieve that? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running `apache` server:

```
sudo nano /etc/crontab
```

Add below line:

```
0 0 * * * root mysqldump -u root -proot db_name > /home/username/db_backup/$( date +"\%Y_\%m_\%d" ).sql
```

> 0 0 * * * => every 24 hours

Comment: That is all I should do? I guess I should replace db_name with the database name and /username/ with my username. Won't I need to do anything else? Set the host/user/pass of the db?

Comment: `0 0 * * *` does not literally mean every 24 hours, but every day at midnight. That's not exactly the same, but other than that, good answer. +1

Comment: @pablito.aven: you need to change `db_name` and directory where you want to put your back up file.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is a linux, you can make a cron using this script : `cronsql.sh` .

```
#!/bin/bash

path=/home/backup/
projet=(databasename1 databasename2)
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")

for arg in ${projet[*]}
do
    if [ ! -d $path$arg ]; then
        mkdir $path$arg
    fi
    cd $path$arg
    mkdir dump$now
    cd dump$now
    mysqldump -dBR --triggers -p"dbpassword" $arg > structure.sql
    mysqldump --no-create-info -p"dbpassword" $arg > data.sql

done
```

It ll generate a folder with database name.
Inside, a folder with date
Inside the folder, a structure.sql file and a data.sql file

```
>databasename1
---->20151009
    ---->data.sql
    ---->structure.sql
---->20151008
    ---->data.sql
    ---->structure.sql
---->20151007
    ---->data.sql
    ---->structure.sql
```

for the cron
use `crontab -e`

then add `59 23 * * * /home/backup/cronsql.sh` if cronsql.sh is in /home/backup/

And last but not least, 
you can add in crontab

```
01 01 * * * find /home/backup/ -mindepth 2 -ctime +30 -exec rm -fr {} +
```

It ll delete every file / folder older than 30 days.
So you have a backup for every last 30days.
And no need to clean it manually

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that you can do it with a *bat, if you are running windows.
This will safe your databases as zip, you also can upload them into ftp by changing this script a little bit.
Follow this link:
**http://www.redolive.com/utah-web-designers-blog/automated-mysql-backup-for-windows/**
It's easy to do, if you have any questions just ask